# Can't iterate through a list of istances of a class

Tags: python, loops, class, instance

I build a list that contains instances of a custom class I create. Now I can access the single attributes like this:

```
 Name_of_list[Index of specific object].attribute1
```

But: If i want to iterate through the bbjects, i can't access the attributes, the following message appears:

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

```
print(list)

[<__main__.Costumer object at 0x00000000118AA3C8>,
<__main__.Costumer object at 0x000000000E3A69E8>,
<__main__.Costumer object at 0x000000000E3A6E10>]
```

Comment: You cannot iterate through raw int, you must wrap it with a range : `for i in range(3): stuff`. Even better : `for obj in obj_list: stuff`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your error is in the loop initializing line

```
for k in 3:
```

you can't use the `in` keyword to iterate, you need to iterate over a sequence which you can generate using `range`

```
>>>for k in range(3):
...    print(k)
0
1
2
```

**Edit**
I see that I got some downvotes, so I thought I'll try to clarify some stuff.
First of all, the OPs question was that he was encountering an error on a line of code, the OPs code has since been removed in an edit.
The code went something in this path

```
class MyClass:
    def attribute(self):
        pass

instances = [MyClass(), MyClass(), MyClass()]

for k in 3:
    instances[k].attribute()
```

and he was getting this error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.
For that I answered (and the OP accepted) that the error is that to use `for` and `in` you need a sequence.
Indeed it is more pythonic (and more readable) to have used

```
for ins in instances:
    ins.attribute()
```

or if there is the need to keep track for the index of the current instance to use `enumerate` which when used along with an iterable it returns a tuple of the index and current object

```
for k, ins in enumerate(instances):
    # k will be the current index, and ins will be the current instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Python lets you iterate over an [iterator object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). You don't need to use `range` and indexes for this, Python does it for you under the hood, as can be seen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335801/695377):

```py
for customer in list:
    print(customer.attribute1)
```

Iterator definition from the docs:

> An object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the iterator’s **next**() method (or passing it to the built-in function next()) return successive items in the stream.