# Trying to check location value for each bucket

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a function in my application which gives me this response:

```
{
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RequestId': 'e7bfcf5f-707e-4526-8b43-077bfa01e9ed', 
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'date': 'Wed, 12 Jun 2019 05:46:37 GMT', 
    }, 
  }, 
  'IsTruncated': False, 
  'Marker': 'foo1', 
  'Buckets': [
    {
      'Name': 'foo2', 
      'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 11, 15, 7, 10, 200000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 
      'Location': 'r1'
    }, {
      'Name': 'foo3', 
      'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 11, 15, 7, 10, 381000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 
      'Location': 'r1'
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check that the `Location`'s in the response = `r1`.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```py
for i in len(resp['Buckets']):
    assert(resp['Buckets'][len(i)]['Location'] == 'r1')
```

I also tried `for i in range(resp['Buckets'])` but get this error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335801/695377) to understand how a Python `for` loop differs from a `while` loop and how it actually works.

Regarding your code, you'd need to loop through `resp['Buckets']` instead of `len(..)`:

```py
for bucket in resp['Buckets']:
    assert bucket['Location'] == 'r1'
```

From what I understand, you're trying to check if **all** buckets have a `location` key with the value of `r1`. A different approach would be to use the `all` method:

```py
all([bucket['Location'] == "r1" for bucket in d['Buckets']])
```